# Pass Credentials in SharePoint Page Viewer

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2007

I am wanting to view web pages on a SharePoint site. A Page Viewer is the obvious way to do this. However, the web pages require authentication. Is it possible to pass the credentials of the current authenticated user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the Type of authentication you have, where the application is hosted (same site or different application).

Refer to these articles for more information  that has same kind of requirement

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086542/page-viewer-webpart-wont-take-login-parameters)

[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112818/displaying-the-current-authenticated-sharepoint-user-from-an-asp-net-page-viewer)